# how to create a tap interface for non-superuser on ubuntu 16.04 xenial

Tags: networking

I had to switch to Ubuntu 16.04 after being a 30 year user of Windows, as my main operating system

```
05:51:33 ~uname -a
Linux y 4.15.0-34-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 28 10:44:06 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have to create a tap interface for GNS3. This install is about 24 hours old and `/etc/network/interfaces` shows only

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I've been trying to create a tap interface for GNS3 for about 12 hours, but I think posts seem to believe I have something already configured. I have nothing. But I am connected to the internet somehow on my ethernet interface

```
05:57:01 ~ifconfig -a
#snip
enxa0cec80e833c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:ce:c8:0e:83:3c  

      inet addr:192.168.1.163  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

How do I create a tap interface to be on the same subnet as enxa0cec80e833c? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried the following
        sudo chown root:netdev /dev/net/turn
        sudo useradd -g x netdev
        (my username on ubuntu is x)
        (my hostname on ubuntu is y)
        sudo tun ctl -u x -g netdev -t tap0
        ifconfig -a
        sudo chown root:netdev /dev/net tun
        sudo ifconfig tap0 192.168.122.254 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
        my ethernet0 interface is inet addr:192.168.1.163  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! What have you tried? Can you edit your answer listing the commands you tried and errors (if any) you got?

Comment: "history 320  ls -al (snip)
    321  sudo tunctl -u x
    322  sudo install uml-utilities
    323  sudo apt-get install uml-utilities
    324  tunctl -u x"325  sudo tunctl -u x
    326  clear
  327  ip link
  328  ifconfig -a
  329  history"

Comment: history (snip)251  sudo chown root:netdev /dev/net/tun
  252  sudo useradd -g x netdev
  253  sudo tunctl -u x -g netdev -t tap0
  254  ifconfig -a
  255  sudo chown root:netdev /dev/net/tun
  256  history
  257  sudo ifconfig tap0 192.168.122.254 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

Comment: please don't post code as comments. Edit your question and format it correctly (either enclosing it with `` or, for multiple lines, prepending 4 spaces).

Comment: i will have to figure out how to properly format my post so it is readable. thank you.

Comment: "251 sudo chown root:netdev /dev/net/tun"

Answer (score 0):

I am reading the ubuntu documentation. I am close to a solution. This question can be marked as answered as I now see a tap0 interface after doing a sudo tunctl -d tap 0, to delete a tap0 interface I created earlier, and then doing a sudo tunctl -u x and then a ifconfig tap0 192.168.1.254 up. I haven't fixed it yet completely , but the interface is there and I can ping it. So I see light at the end of the tunnel and I require no further help. Thank you.